# What's causing this resizable div to overflow its 100% height container?

Tags: html, css

If you drag the resizeable yellow div up to its maximum possible height, it will overflow and a scrollbar is displayed.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: table;
}
.header {
    background-color: green;
    height:100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.content {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color:white;
    display: table-row;

}

.control {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div  class="control">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's causing this and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the yellow box keeps getting bigger until it overflows the container; you can prevent this using CSS `max-height: 100%`. The problem with this is that the container keeps expanding as the yellow box expands, so the yellow box never actually fills the available space. I fixed this by giving the container `position: relative` and the resizable control `position: absolute`.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}
.header {
    background-color: green;
    height:100%;
    display: table-row;
}
.content {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color:white;
    display: table-row;

}

.control {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div  class="control">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. . A solution that doesn't require absolute positioning would be ideal as the green .header div doesn't resize with this method.